# Sending nested json object in POST method using Postman to Spring REST API

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, postman

i am trying to send nested json object in POST request to my spring REST API.

Object java code

```
public class TestModel {
private String id;
private String name;

public TestModel(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

---

Post method code in rest controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloPost")
public ResponseEntity<TestModel> helloPost(@RequestBody TestModel t) {
    return new ResponseEntity<TestModel>(t, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

---

My postman screenshot

[image]

---

It has to return status 200 ok and object i sent, but it returns 400 bad request permanently.
Please, tell me what am i doing wrong. It was ok when i sent one string(my @RequestBody was string too) but completly not working with custom objects.

P.S
i have added comma, no changes

Comment: In the test model, please add the default constructor and try. Also, add consumes annotation with content type value as application json. Set it in the request header as well.

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot

Comment: Problem resolved?

Comment: Please add the error you getting now.

Comment: no error, its working now, after adding default constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, please add the default constructor for TestModel class. It should resolve the problem.

As an additional step, if the web service is going to accept json as input, then add consumes annotation with content type as application json.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the "," after the id field in JSON. proper JSON is your case would be below :-

```
{
"id" : "1",
"name" : "test"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a malformed json you are sending to the server. You need to add comma to separate elements in json.

Even postman showing wrong icon at the left.

```
{
"id" : 1,
"name" : "test"
}
```

Also you need to add setters and default constructor in object model to set those values.